# How can I log something with python logger only when an assert fails?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, logging, pytest

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetUp","setUp")
class BeyondTest(unittest.TestCase):
    log = cl.testLogger(logging.INFO)
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self,oneTimeSetUp):
        self.ts = TestStatus(self.driver)
        self.bmf = BMF(self.driver)


    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_site_to_csv(self):
        self.bmf.imagelist()
        first_column =[l[4] for l in self.bmf.csvreader]
        list_site_to_csv = [item for item in self.bmf.full_list if item not in first_column]
        self.log.INFO(list_site_to_csv)
        assert len(list_site_to_csv)<=0
```

So I have a csv with some data that needs to be verified on a site, I first capture data on the site append to a list "self.bmf.full_list", the csv columns are saved in the first_column list,
I then compare both list and save the ones missing from csv but are present on site to the list "list_site_to_csv. The assertion is the len(list_site_to_csv)<=0. What I am trying to figure out is how to log.INFO only when an assertion fails? something like

```
if assert len(list_site_to_csv)<=0:
    then self.log.INFO(list_site_to_csv)
```

anyother suggestion on better way to handle this than a list would also be great

Comment: And you don't just want an if-statement? You could put the assertion in a `try`/`except` block to catch the exception, log, then raise the exception.

Answer (score 1):

`assert` accepts a second argument. Example:

```
>>> list_site_to_csv = ['apples']
>>> assert not list_site_to_csv, f'It failed. List is not empty. {list_site_to_csv}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError: It failed. List is not empty. ['apples']
```

In this case if the `list_site_to_csv` is not empty, the assert will pops out, and it'll show the message.

Note:

len(list_site_to_csv) <= 0 is not pythonic. For testing falsy values it's preferred to use `if not my_var:`.